# Trouble with strcpy

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm terrible with C, and am having trouble with strcpy. I'm trying to grab one of the function arguments and store it in a char array. When I run this, I get a segmentation fault, but I don't see why. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
struct bb_state {
    FILE *logfile;
    char *rootdir;
};

struct bb_state *bb_data;
bb_data = malloc(sizeof(struct bb_state));
strcpy(bb_data->rootdir, argv[argc-2]);
```

Comment: There is a need to ensure the area the pointer(`bb_data->rootdir`) is pointing.

Comment: Did you check size of the `bb_data->rootdir` . In `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source )` :To avoid **overflows**, the size of the array pointed by **destination** shall be long enough to contain the same C string as **source** (including the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must allocate memory for `char* rootdir`.

Example:

```
int len=strlen(argv[argc-2])+1;
bb_data->rootdir=malloc(len);
```

and after that you can do:

```
strcpy(bb_data->rootdir, argv[argc-2]);
```

Comment: If `strdup` is available it could perform the above steps in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for `rootdir`. Estimate how many characters you are trying to copy and you can do another `malloc` for `rootdir`:

Make sure `argv` is big enough to be indexed using `argc-2`.  This could also cause crash.

```
bb_data->rootdir = malloc(strlen(argv[argc-2]+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to grab one of the function arguments and **store it in a char array**.

The problem with your code is that you don't have a character **array** in which to store the copied argument. What you have is a pointer. You must allocate storage in which to copy the argument. Or, you can make `rootdir` be an array instead of a pointer, but you must be careful to prevent the copy from overflowing the fixed-size array.

**Allocate storage**

```
bb_data->rootdir = malloc(strlen(argv[argc - 2]) + 1); // +1 is for the NULL
```

**Make rootdir an array**

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

    struct bb_state {
        FILE *logfile;
        char  rootdir [PATH_MAX];
    };

    struct bb_state *bb_data;
    size_t           len;
    len = strlen(argv[argc - 2]);
    if (len >= PATH_MAX) {
        // Argument is too long.
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument is too long: %s\n", argv[argc - 2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    bb_data = malloc(sizeof(struct bb_state));
    strcpy(bb_data->rootdir, argv[argc - 2]);
```